# Sas macro: Run macro per element in array

Tags: sas

I am trying to call another macro for each element in an array. This is an easier description of the same problem. I would expect that the macro prints each var in another row, but it does not. Why? How can this be fixed?

```
%macro test(varlist);
%local var i ;
%do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist)) ;
  %let var = %scan(&varlist,&i) ;
  %put looped var is &var;

%end ;
%mend test;

%test(var1 var2 var3)
```

Comment: Can you show us the log and what you expect?  I don't fully understand what you are looking for.

Comment: i would expect var1 \n var2 \n var3 \n in the log, but there is nothing from put in the log at all, nothing gets printed to the log.

Comment: Your code works fine.  Perhaps you just need to restart SAS and submit it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS Macro does not contain an array structure.  However, in SAS Macro, a textual sequence depicting a list of delimited items can be processed in an array like manner.  The items depicted can represent other things that can be further utilized or emitted as source code for further processing.

The code as posted does **log** one line per item in the space separated list of what you are calling variable names.

SAS Log

```
1    %macro test(varlist);
2    %local var i ;
3    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist)) ;
4      %let var = %scan(&varlist,&i) ;
5      %put looped var is &var;
6
7    %end ;
8    %mend test;
9
10   %test(var1 var2 var3)
looped var is var1
looped var is var2
looped var is var3
```

For the case of code, especially macro code, not loggin information when expected there is likely other programming statements that are incorrect and changing the expected state.  You might have unbalanced quotes that are causing the macro source code to be considered part of another step.  Sometimes, when the executor can't be returned to a proper 'ready' state, a restart of the SAS session is the best course of action.

Comment: thanks richard. I'll later test if that solves my problem and accept accordingly.